# jQuery Mobile modification of header not persistent

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQuery Mobile site which has a button in the header. The Code is:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header" id="theheader">
  <a href="/userAdd" data-icon="puls" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="notext">a</a>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <a href="/userShow" data-icon="star" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="notext" 
     id="notifybutton">x</a>
</div>
```

Now I have an ajax which changes the data-theme of the notifybutton like:

```
setInterval(function () {
         $.get("/ajaxCheckNotifications", function(data){
            if (data != "0"){
                $("#notifybutton").buttonMarkup({theme: 'c'});
            }else{
                    $("#notifybutton").buttonMarkup({theme: 'b'});
            }
       });
}, 2500)
```

This works fine when I load the page (F5).

But as soon as I a new page is loaded through the ajax loader the theme is not kept. And even worse the next time the ajax is run the button is not updated anymore. I have tried pretty much everything from .trigger('pagecreate') to getItemById.

Thank you ever so much for any help.

Comment: You will need to show us more code then this. What is your paga layout? At what point are you calling this function?

Comment: The function is called ever 2500 milliseconds through the setInterval. Every PageDiv has the save header.